# изменение размера, перемещение и поворот QWidget во время работы программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

У меня есть QWidget и мне нужно изменять его размер, перемещать и поворачивать по форме (как в Фотошоп или QtDesigner).

Это всё должно быть во время работы приложения.

Помогите пожалуйста и нет я не Фотошоп делаю.

***Вот мой код перемещения, но вот изменение размера и поворот я не где в Google не нашёл:***
'''

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.__mousePressPos = None
    self.__mouseMovePos = None
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
        self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()
    super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
        # adjust offset from clicked point to origin of widget
        currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
        globalPos = event.globalPos()
        diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
        newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
        self.move(newPos)
        self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos
    super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
        moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos 
        if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
            event.ignore()
            return
    super(DragButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

'''

Comment: Вам нужно воспользоваться `QGraphicsView`, `QGraphicsScene` и самое главное, вот этим `QGraphicsProxyWidget` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html при помощи которого вы сможете делать со своим виджетом все, что захотите

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Я новичок, подскажи как это сделать. И напиши в ответах. Пожалуйста :) И реальный размер и реальное положение виджета используется в расчётах.

Comment: Вот пример (на С++, но в принципе на питоне все тоже самое). https://progi.pro/sdelat-qgraphicsproxywidget-podvizhnim-i-vibiraemim-3510338. Вот еще пример, уже на PyQt5 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42182399/4711135. Почитайте (в том числе документацию), посмотрите, потом попробуйте сами - не будет получаться - приходите, посмотрим

Comment: Там только перемещение и поворот, а мне ещё надо изменение размеров.

Comment: И у меня должен быть один независимый элемент который я просто объявляю указываю начальный размер и всё, а там какая то дополнительная форма. Если эту Фому не убрать то можно сделать так чтобы элемент был как отдельный объект на этой форме, потому что я их храню в списке. И использую для сборки кода для дисплея. И можно пожалуйста на Python :)

Comment: И я плохо знаю C++ :)

Comment: А можно как то дать возможность перемещать, переворачивать и изменять размер пользователю, как в Фотошопе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример использования `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, может быть это ваш случай

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView

if __name__=='__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)

  scene = QGraphicsScene()
  view = QGraphicsView(scene)
  view.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)
  view.show()

  widget = QWidget() # << Ваш виджет
  proxy = scene.addWidget(widget)

  // Модифицируем виджет, используя его прокси
  // Масштаб
  proxy.setScale(2.0)
  // Вращение
  proxy.setRotation(30)

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QGraphicsView.html) есть такое предупреждение:

> Using an OpenGL viewport limits the ability to use
> QGraphicsProxyWidget . Not all combinations of widgets and styles can
> be supported with such a setup. You should carefully test your UI and
> make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: А можно как то дать возможность перемещать, переворачивать и изменять размер пользователю, как в Фотошопе.

Comment: Если можно то ответе или в комментариях или в ответах. Пожалуйста :)

Comment: @ардуиноIDE это уже за большие деньги. Если серьезно, то попробуйте сами - в интернете полно примеров работы с `QGraphicsScene` и `QGraphicsItem` ) Вот, например, так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199823/235611